# Changing the speeds of vehicles at different times

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm using Omnet++ 5.0, and SUMO 0.25.0, and I'm trying to change the speed of vehicles at certain times. For example, i'm trying to set the speed of the vehicles near the intersection to 0.0, but then after a while i want to move so I'm changing the speed. The vehicles on the same road should be able to move, but the lower lane is the only one responding to the change of the speed, and they move into the intersection to cross it, and ones in the higher lane shown with an arrow are not moving at all.
i tried to monitor the speed of the first vehicle (its ID is 20) in the higher lane, and it shows that the speed keeps on minimizing instead of being changed using the setSpeed().

[image]

1st image is the code when setting the speed to 0.0.
2nd image when setting the speed to 13.89
3rd image showing the vehicles, the lower lane in the road to the right are responding to the second command (13.89) unlike the higher lane
the vehicle circled is vehicle 20

```
Vehicle ID 20
Lane ID -171270025#1_0
Speed 10.2666
Speed after setSpeed(13.89) 10.2666
Vehicle 20 Speed:9.97035
Vehicle 20 Speed:9.65099
Vehicle 20 Speed:9.33599
Vehicle 20 Speed:9.02479
Vehicle 20 Speed:8.71445
Vehicle 20 Speed:8.40909
...
```

and it keeps on minimizing until it reaches up to this point

```
Vehicle 20 Speed:0.000168397
Vehicle 20 Speed:0.000151557
Vehicle 20 Speed:0.000136401
Vehicle 20 Speed:0.000122761
Vehicle 20 Speed:0.000110485
Vehicle 20 Speed:9.94365e-005
Vehicle 20 Speed:8.94929e-005
```

can you suggest something that will help me solve this problem? Thank you!

update:
these are the functions used in the vehicle side in TraCIDemo
to make it short the vehicle requests the permission from the RSU to pass the intersection. Though the vehicles receive the permission, some do not change the speed and move to cross the intersection.

```
void MyTraCIDemo11p::onDataCross(CrossFromControllerMessage* csm) { // this is the function that is used when receiving the permission to cross, and changes the speed.
    int n = 0;
std::string vehichleId = mobility->getExternalId();
  for (int i=0 ; i < csm->getVehiclesListArraySize();i++) // this is a list received from the RSU to notify which vehicle to cross the intersection
            {
                vehicleList.push_back(std::string(csm->getVehiclesList(i)));

            }

  std::list<std::string>::iterator ttry1;
  ttry1 = std::find(vehicleList.begin(), vehicleList.end(), vehichleId);
  if (vehichleId == *ttry1){
      n = 1;
  }
   if (state == WAITING && n == 1  ){
                    findHost()->bubble("Received");
                    state = QUEUING;
                    stateToString(state);

                    traciVehicle->setSpeed(13.89);


    }

}
```

This is the handle position function. it manages the states of the vehicles based on their positions, and exchange of messages with the RSU.
the states of the vehicles change as follows Idle-> Waiting-> Queuing-> crossing-> Idle

```
void MyTraCIDemo11p::handlePositionUpdate(cObject* obj) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::handlePositionUpdate(obj);
     vehiclePosition= mobility->getCurrentPosition();
     junctionPosition = traci->junction("1823290733").getPosition();

     if ( vehiclePosition.distance(junctionPosition) < 10) // this cas when the vehicle is inside the intersection
         {
             state = CROSSING;
             stateToString(state);
         } else if (vehiclePosition.distance(junctionPosition) < 30 && vehiclePosition.distance(junctionPosition) > 10 && state == IDLE && !sentRequestMessage ) // this case when the vehicle just reached the intersection

         {
                traciVehicle->setSpeed(0.0);
                sendRequestMessage(mobility->getExternalId(),traciVehicle->getLaneId()); // it sends a message to the RSU to allow it to cross the intersection
                state = WAITING;
                stateToString(state);


        } else if ((state == CROSSING) && vehiclePosition.distance(junctionPosition) < 9) // this case when the vehicle is passing the intersection 
        {
            findHost()->bubble("i'm crossing");
             state = CROSSED;
             stateToString(state);


         }else if (state == CROSSED) // this case when the vehicle crossed the intersection completely 
         {
             if (!sentCrossedMessage){
                 sendCrossedMessage(mobility->getExternalId()); //it sends a message to the RSU that it crossed
                 state = IDLE;
                 stateToString(state);
                 }

         }else if (state==QUEUING){ // this is when the vehicle is still at the intersection but received the persmission from the RSU to pass the intersection

                                 traciVehicle->setSpeed(13.89);

                             }
                       }
                 }
         }

}
```

// this is the stateToString function used in the handle position

```
 virtual std::string stateToString(State state) const {

            std::string s ;
                switch(state)
                {

                    case IDLE:
                        s = "IDLE";
                        break;

                    case WAITING:
                        s =  "WAITING";
                        break;

                    case QUEUING:
                        s =  "QUEUING";
                        break;

                    case CROSSING:
                        s =  "CROSSING";
                        break;

                    case CROSSED:
                        s =  "CROSSED";
                        break;
                    }
                return s;

                }
```

i will include the map xml below
This is the erlangen.net.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- generated on 12/22/2016 12:09:17 AM by Netedit Version 0.25.0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/netedit.exeConfiguration.xsd">

    <input>
        <sumo-net-file value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\MAP\map.net.xml"/>
    </input>

    <output>
        <output-file value="C:\Users\user\Desktop\MAP\map.net.xml"/>
    </output>

    <processing>
        <no-turnarounds value="true"/>
        <offset.disable-normalization value="true"/>
        <lefthand value="false"/>
        <junctions.corner-detail value="0"/>
    </processing>

</configuration>
-->

<net version="0.25" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/net_file.xsd">

    <location netOffset="-239463.70,-2703699.84" convBoundary="0.00,0.00,484.43,238.03" origBoundary="54.430493,24.425071,54.435282,24.427224" projParameter="+proj=utm +zone=40 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"/>

    <edge id=":1823286480_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823286480_0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="4.82" shape="362.07,237.77 361.45,239.12 360.70,239.66 359.82,239.38 358.81,238.29"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823289120_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823289120_0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="4.82" shape="484.14,100.03 485.51,100.63 486.06,101.37 485.79,102.26 484.72,103.29"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823289179_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823289179_0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="4.82" shape="0.28,186.90 -1.08,186.29 -1.63,185.55 -1.36,184.67 -0.28,183.64"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="16.31" shape="339.27,135.29 338.52,130.51 338.01,127.23 337.49,123.96 336.74,119.18"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_1" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_1_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="10.91" shape="342.53,134.78 342.47,130.45 343.81,127.12 346.09,125.17"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_8" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_8_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="4.93" shape="346.09,125.17 346.54,124.79 350.66,123.44"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_2" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_2_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="16.33" shape="351.80,129.94 347.03,130.78 343.76,131.35 340.49,131.91 335.71,132.73"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_3" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_3_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="15.80" shape="351.23,126.69 346.89,126.83 343.57,125.54 341.28,122.82 340.00,118.67"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_4" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_4_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="16.31" shape="346.52,117.64 347.27,122.43 347.79,125.70 348.30,128.97 349.05,133.75"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_5" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_5_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="10.93" shape="343.26,118.15 343.33,122.49 342.00,125.82 339.71,127.78"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_9" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_9_0" index="0" speed="13.89" length="4.91" shape="339.71,127.78 339.27,128.16 335.15,129.48"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_6" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_6_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="16.29" shape="334.04,122.98 338.81,122.16 342.07,121.60 345.33,121.03 350.09,120.19"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823290733_7" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823290733_7_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="15.77" shape="334.60,126.23 338.92,126.11 342.23,127.41 344.52,130.13 345.79,134.27"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id=":1823291283_0" function="internal">
        <lane id=":1823291283_0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="4.82" shape="321.39,0.26 322.01,-1.09 322.76,-1.63 323.64,-1.35 324.65,-0.26"/>
    </edge>

    <edge id="-171270025#0" from="1823290733" to="1823289179" priority="4" type="highway.residential">
        <lane id="-171270025#0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="339.76" shape="335.71,132.73 0.84,190.15"/>
        <lane id="-171270025#0_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="339.76" shape="335.15,129.48 0.28,186.90"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="-171270025#1" from="1823289120" to="1823290733" priority="4" type="highway.residential">
        <lane id="-171270025#1_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="135.52" shape="485.29,106.54 351.80,129.94"/>
        <lane id="-171270025#1_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="135.52" shape="484.72,103.29 351.23,126.69"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="-171270266#0" from="1823290733" to="1823286480" priority="4" type="highway.residential">
        <lane id="-171270266#0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="104.78" shape="349.05,133.75 365.33,237.26"/>
        <lane id="-171270266#0_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="104.78" shape="345.79,134.27 362.07,237.77"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="-171270266#1" from="1823291283" to="1823290733" priority="4" type="highway.residential" shape="323.02,0.00 325.45,15.47 328.84,37.02 339.41,104.25 342.90,126.48">
        <lane id="-171270266#1_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="119.86" shape="327.91,-0.77 330.34,14.70 333.73,36.25 344.30,103.48 346.52,117.64"/>
        <lane id="-171270266#1_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="119.86" shape="324.65,-0.26 327.08,15.21 330.47,36.76 341.04,103.99 343.26,118.15"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="171270025#0" from="1823289179" to="1823290733" priority="4" type="highway.residential">
        <lane id="171270025#0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="339.76" shape="-0.84,180.39 334.04,122.98"/>
        <lane id="171270025#0_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="339.76" shape="-0.28,183.64 334.60,126.23"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="171270025#1" from="1823290733" to="1823289120" priority="4" type="highway.residential">
        <lane id="171270025#1_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="135.52" shape="350.09,120.19 483.57,96.78"/>
        <lane id="171270025#1_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="135.52" shape="350.66,123.44 484.14,100.03"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="171270266#0" from="1823286480" to="1823290733" priority="4" type="highway.residential">
        <lane id="171270266#0_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="104.78" shape="355.55,238.80 339.27,135.29"/>
        <lane id="171270266#0_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="104.78" shape="358.81,238.29 342.53,134.78"/>
    </edge>
    <edge id="171270266#1" from="1823290733" to="1823291283" priority="4" type="highway.residential" shape="342.90,126.48 339.41,104.25 328.84,37.02 325.45,15.47 323.02,0.00">
        <lane id="171270266#1_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="119.86" shape="336.74,119.18 334.52,105.02 323.95,37.79 320.56,16.24 318.13,0.77"/>
        <lane id="171270266#1_1" index="1" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="13.89" length="119.86" shape="340.00,118.67 337.78,104.51 327.21,37.28 323.82,15.73 321.39,0.26"/>
    </edge>

    <junction id="1823286480" type="priority" x="360.44" y="238.03" incLanes="-171270266#0_0 -171270266#0_1" intLanes=":1823286480_0_0" shape="360.39,238.04 353.97,239.05 366.91,237.01 360.49,238.02">
        <request index="0" response="0" foes="0" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="1823289120" type="priority" x="484.43" y="101.66" incLanes="171270025#1_0 171270025#1_1" intLanes=":1823289120_0_0" shape="484.44,101.71 485.56,108.11 483.30,95.21 484.42,101.61">
        <request index="0" response="0" foes="0" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="1823289179" type="priority" x="0.00" y="185.27" incLanes="-171270025#0_0 -171270025#0_1" intLanes=":1823289179_0_0" shape="-0.01,185.22 -1.11,178.81 1.11,191.73 0.01,185.32">
        <request index="0" response="0" foes="0" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="1823290733" type="priority" x="342.90" y="126.48" incLanes="171270266#0_0 171270266#0_1 -171270025#1_0 -171270025#1_1 -171270266#1_0 -171270266#1_1 171270025#0_0 171270025#0_1" intLanes=":1823290733_0_0 :1823290733_8_0 :1823290733_2_0 :1823290733_3_0 :1823290733_4_0 :1823290733_9_0 :1823290733_6_0 :1823290733_7_0" shape="337.69,135.54 350.64,133.51 352.08,131.52 349.81,118.62 348.10,117.39 335.16,119.43 333.77,121.40 335.98,134.31">
        <request index="0" response="00000000" foes="11100100" cont="0"/>
        <request index="1" response="00010000" foes="10011100" cont="1"/>
        <request index="2" response="00010011" foes="10010011" cont="0"/>
        <request index="3" response="01110010" foes="01110010" cont="0"/>
        <request index="4" response="00000000" foes="01001110" cont="0"/>
        <request index="5" response="00000001" foes="11001001" cont="1"/>
        <request index="6" response="00110001" foes="00111001" cont="0"/>
        <request index="7" response="00100111" foes="00100111" cont="0"/>
    </junction>
    <junction id="1823291283" type="priority" x="323.02" y="0.00" incLanes="171270266#1_0 171270266#1_1" intLanes=":1823291283_0_0" shape="323.07,-0.01 329.49,-1.02 316.55,1.02 322.97,0.01">
        <request index="0" response="0" foes="0" cont="0"/>
    </junction>

    <junction id=":1823290733_8_0" type="internal" x="346.09" y="125.17" incLanes=":1823290733_1_0 -171270266#1_0" intLanes=":1823290733_2_0 :1823290733_3_0 :1823290733_4_0 :1823290733_7_0"/>
    <junction id=":1823290733_9_0" type="internal" x="339.71" y="127.78" incLanes=":1823290733_5_0 171270266#0_0" intLanes=":1823290733_0_0 :1823290733_3_0 :1823290733_6_0 :1823290733_7_0"/>

    <connection from="-171270025#0" to="171270025#0" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823289179_0_0" dir="t" state="M"/>
    <connection from="-171270025#1" to="-171270025#0" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":1823290733_2_0" dir="s" state="m"/>
    <connection from="-171270025#1" to="171270266#1" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823290733_3_0" dir="l" state="m"/>
    <connection from="-171270266#0" to="171270266#0" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823286480_0_0" dir="t" state="M"/>
    <connection from="-171270266#1" to="-171270266#0" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":1823290733_4_0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from="-171270266#1" to="-171270025#0" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823290733_5_0" dir="l" state="m"/>
    <connection from="171270025#0" to="171270025#1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":1823290733_6_0" dir="s" state="m"/>
    <connection from="171270025#0" to="-171270266#0" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823290733_7_0" dir="l" state="m"/>
    <connection from="171270025#1" to="-171270025#1" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823289120_0_0" dir="t" state="M"/>
    <connection from="171270266#0" to="171270266#1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" via=":1823290733_0_0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from="171270266#0" to="171270025#1" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823290733_1_0" dir="l" state="m"/>
    <connection from="171270266#1" to="-171270266#1" fromLane="1" toLane="1" via=":1823291283_0_0" dir="t" state="M"/>

    <connection from=":1823286480_0" to="171270266#0" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823289120_0" to="-171270025#1" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823289179_0" to="171270025#0" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_0" to="171270266#1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_1" to="171270025#1" fromLane="0" toLane="1" via=":1823290733_8_0" dir="s" state="m"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_8" to="171270025#1" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_2" to="-171270025#0" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_3" to="171270266#1" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_4" to="-171270266#0" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_5" to="-171270025#0" fromLane="0" toLane="1" via=":1823290733_9_0" dir="s" state="m"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_9" to="-171270025#0" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_6" to="171270025#1" fromLane="0" toLane="0" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823290733_7" to="-171270266#0" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>
    <connection from=":1823291283_0" to="-171270266#1" fromLane="0" toLane="1" dir="s" state="M"/>

</net>
```

This is erlangen.poly.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- generated on 12/22/16 00:09:29 by SUMO polyconvert Version 0.25.0
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/polyconvertConfiguration.xsd">

    <input>
        <net-file value="map.net.xml"/>
        <osm-files value="map.osm"/>
        <type-file value="typemap.xml"/>
    </input>

    <output>
        <output-file value="map.poly.xml"/>
    </output>

    <processing>
        <poi-layer-offset value="5"/>
    </processing>

</configuration>
-->

<additional xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/additional_file.xsd">
    <location netOffset="-239463.70,-2703699.84" convBoundary="-0.00,0.00,484.43,241.92" origBoundary="54.430493,24.425071,54.435282,24.427244" projParameter="+proj=utm +zone=40 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"/>

    <poly id="171270235" type="parking" color="184,184,179" fill="1" layer="-1.00" shape="328.55,111.49 336.20,110.20 323.37,34.75 315.71,36.04 328.55,111.49"/>
    <poly id="171270768" type="parking" color="184,184,179" fill="1" layer="-1.00" shape="349.14,225.19 369.11,221.68 353.65,134.84 333.69,138.36 349.14,225.19"/>
    <poly id="231986403" type="building" color="255,230,230" fill="1" layer="-1.00" shape="393.78,103.22 362.66,108.50 360.32,94.90 355.82,95.67 353.28,80.84 357.82,80.07 357.56,78.56 354.20,79.13 352.62,69.93 382.34,64.88 382.67,66.83 387.40,66.02 391.60,90.49 393.78,103.22"/>
    <poly id="397635254" type="natural" color="140,196,107" fill="1" layer="-4.00" shape="269.58,241.92 252.16,146.52 334.19,131.69 337.75,132.71 339.70,135.37 332.44,136.52 346.79,227.28 354.13,226.13 354.80,230.38 353.77,233.64 339.69,236.19 338.46,229.47 269.58,241.92"/>
    <poly id="397652904" type="landuse" color="194,194,130" fill="1" layer="-3.00" shape="373.54,198.63 362.71,132.40 373.75,130.61 376.42,146.92 379.08,163.20 381.61,178.69 381.83,180.01 377.02,180.80 379.76,197.62 373.54,198.63"/>
    <poly id="397656745" type="natural" color="140,196,107" fill="1" layer="-4.00" shape="346.63,134.59 346.94,132.62 348.39,130.57 351.23,129.43 481.72,107.10 482.29,110.29 481.38,110.18 362.02,131.61 373.34,198.77 379.76,197.62 382.03,212.19 376.62,213.14 377.75,219.58 377.27,221.69 378.50,229.38 366.98,231.49 363.69,230.33 361.74,228.21 361.13,224.69 370.09,223.04 354.40,133.34 346.63,134.59"/>
    <poly id="397658254" type="landuse" color="194,194,130" fill="1" layer="-3.00" shape="391.60,90.49 400.82,81.96 405.76,108.70 360.25,116.76 355.82,95.67 360.32,94.90 362.66,108.50 393.78,103.22 391.60,90.49"/>
    <poly id="397658256" type="landuse" color="194,194,130" fill="1" layer="-3.00" shape="350.68,118.49 358.39,117.15 351.86,79.91 353.01,79.71 351.15,69.14 363.31,67.02 344.15,35.03 342.90,33.70 338.47,7.10 335.18,4.47 332.18,3.84 326.92,4.76 325.90,7.16 331.93,41.50 337.00,40.62 350.68,118.49"/>
    <poly id="397658423" type="parking" color="184,184,179" fill="1" layer="-1.00" shape="341.63,118.05 349.28,116.75 336.45,41.30 328.79,42.59 341.63,118.05"/>
    <poly id="397772846" type="landuse" color="194,194,130" fill="1" layer="-3.00" shape="294.28,115.99 296.13,127.03 318.16,123.38 317.45,119.17 320.63,118.65 323.51,112.37 318.79,84.17 304.52,86.53 305.15,90.31 312.71,89.06 315.88,108.05 301.81,110.38 302.51,114.63 294.28,115.99"/>
    <poly id="397773661" type="landuse" color="194,194,130" fill="1" layer="-3.00" shape="323.47,118.55 334.65,116.57 335.25,119.88 324.07,121.86 323.47,118.55"/>
</additional>
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal, complete, working example of a simulation that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: Yea I do. I added the image attached in the post to show parts of the code.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error with the part of the code visible in your screenshot. I could not. This is why I was asking.

Comment: Should I attach the whole vehicle code here?

Comment: Please make the example simulation as short as possible. Ideally, modify a simulation everyone already has (such as the tutorial simulation or the one in the tests directory). This way you might not need to include more than a few lines of code in your post. The more code you include the harder it is to identify the problem.

Comment: Ok. Will edit it, and also include the map used, and then get back to you.

Comment: I added the code with the map xml files. =)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not make myself clear. I was asking you to share the smallest possible modification to a publicly-available (working) simulation that still triggers your problem. You seem to have shared large parts of the Veins tutorial simulation, large parts of irrelevant code (such as `stateToString`), and omitted part of the code that triggers your problem (such as where `onDataCross` is called)

Comment: my problem is mainly triggered in onDataCross, and on the handlePostion Function that's why i put them. i actually removed a huge part from it, and minimized it as much as possible.

Comment: Just to be clear. I'm using a different map with 1 intersection only, and that's why I included it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated file by SUMO was corrupted so generating a new one solved the problem.